# Alembic MSSQL Unique Constraint Allow Nulls

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, alembic

## Problem to Solve

Using MSSQL I'd like to have a column that is unique and accepts nulls.

## Issues

1. Add two rows of data into a column that allows nulls with the unique constraint like in the implementation below gives the following error:

   ```
   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_...'. Cannot insert duplicate key in 
   object 'TABLE'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>). (2627) (SQLExecDirectW)"
   ```
2. Downgrading the column causes constraint issues tied to the `reference` column. The constraint is automatically uniquely named so its a pain to programmatically remove.

## Current Implementation

The alembic operation is:

```py
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

#...

def upgrade():
    op.add_column(
        'TABLE', sa.Column('reference', sa.Integer(), nullable=True, unique=True),
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_column('TABLE', 'reference')
```

Comment: Isn't that what is in the answer below? Its in the `upgrade` function

Comment: No Worries. I didn't make the answer clear enough :). I just expanded the answer. Hopefully that makes it a bit more clearer

Answer (score 0):

The solution to allowing nulls in a unique field is:

1. Don't create the unique constraint when defining the column

```py
op.add_column(
        'TABLE', sa.Column('reference', sa.Integer(), nullable=True), # No unique=True
    )
```

2. Create a [unique index](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_index) manually

```py
op.create_index(
    'uq_reference_allow_nulls', table_name='TABLE', columns=['reference'],
    mssql_where=sa.text('reference IS NOT NULL'), unique=True,
)
```

3. Remove the index when downgrading.

```py
op.drop_index('uq_reference_allow_nulls', table_name='TABLE')
```

This also solves the problem of having a randomized unique constraint on the table because the `unique` parameter is removed. All together the alembic revision looks like this:

```py
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

#...

def upgrade():
    op.add_column(
        'TABLE', sa.Column('reference', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),  # Do not include unique here
    )
    op.create_index(
        'uq_reference_allow_nulls', table_name='TABLE', columns=['reference'],
        mssql_where=sa.text('reference IS NOT NULL'), unique=True,
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_index('uq_reference_allow_nulls', table_name='TABLE')
    op.drop_column('TABLE', 'reference')
```